# Можно ли запустить эмулятор Android с браузером и получить вывод веб-консоли?

Tags: android, google-chrome, эмулятор

Есть проблема: нет Android устройства для подключения через USB и подсоединения Chrome к мобильному Chrome. Можно ли это провернуть через эмулятор?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В моем случае мне помогло решение с этого сайта - http://jsconsole.com/
Оно позволяет работать с консолью удаленно, необходимо только подключить скрипт.

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендую использовать сторонний эмулятор [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/). Он ведет себя более аналогично реальному девайсу.
Вывод в консоль настраивается точно так же, как и для реального девайса.

Comment: Да, но как я понял, там надо за многое платить, и подключение через usb и доступ к сети являются платными услугами.

Comment: @alexkai, нет. Ни то ни другое. Это все бесплатно